# Backbone view is not refreshed according to model.bind

Tags: backbone.js

I have an index.html which looks like this -

```
    <div id="header">
         <div id="form"></div>
    </div>   

    <div><ul id="admin_list"></ul></div>
```

The backbone header view is defined as follows -

```
      var headerView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#header", 
        initialize: function(){
            this.render(); 
        },
        events: {
            "click #save": "save_form"
        },
        save_form: function(){
             this.model.save();
             return false;   
        }, 
        render: function(){
             var template = _.template($("#tmpl_form").html()); 
             $(this.el).html(template);
        }
    });
```

The view for the admin list is given below -

```
     var adminView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#admin_list", 
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
            this.model.bind("add", this.render, this);
        },
        render: function(){
            $(this.el).html("<li>New Model Added</li>");
        }
     });
```

Finally, I create an instance of the headerView and adminView

```
      var header_View =  new headerView();
      header_View.render();
```

My question is, when I save the model the admin_list does not get refreshed with a new li item "New Model Added". I presume, `this.model.bind("add", this.render, this)` isn't getting called.

Could somebody throw some light on this please!

Cheers!

Comment: Another thing i noticed, you render your headerview double, once after instanciating it and once in the initialize method

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you are not creating the admin view, only the
header view. Also, you need to pass the collection to the views:

```
var header_View =  new headerView({collection: your_list});
var admin_View =  new adminView({collection: your_list});
```

Comment: If I use $("#header") then my header_view should be instantiated in the $(document).ready(function){}); If not, I can define the el: "#header".

Answer (score 0):

The add event for the model will only fire if it's added to a collection. If you are just saving the model and want to re-render adminView after it is successfully persisted on the server, I believe you will need to add your own event, ex:

```
myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    save: function(attrs, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        var success = options.success || null;
        var model = this;
        options.success = function(model, resp) {
            model.trigger('saved', model);
            if (success) success(model, resp);
        };
        Backbone.Model.prototype.save.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

And then in adminView.initialize, bind to 'saved' instead of 'add'.